# GTFS vs SIRI wich one is more used nowaday

Tags: uses-of-open-data, public-transport

i 've searched a lot for this kind of information unfortunaetly  i can't find the right information about , we know all that gtfs was 
Standarisedby google the last 3 years , siri was and still used  especially in Europe , for those who have an idea or have worked with these kind of feeds files   wich one should i use for my web application destined to bus transit ?